# String parsing - Program crashes when free() is called after memory reallocation failure or end of program.

Tags: c

I am trying to separate numbers from other characters in a string by storing them in two separate arrays. For example if I put, 11+22+33 into the console the program should put the variables array as {11,22,33} and  function array as {+,+}.

First, my reallocation for the variables always fails (for myself) at the 8th reallocation.  This in itself is a problem, however to try and deal with this potential situation the program should free all the memory used and return 1. Instead the program crashes at the `free()`'s.

The second problem is if the memory reallocation doesn't fail, the program continues to the end and then crashes once again at the `free()` functions.

I believe it is to do with over running the memory block (past experience intuition), however I can not see where I would overrun the last memory cell.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int functionLocation,i, Counter=0,fCounter=0,vCounter=0;
    double *variables=NULL;
    char *function=NULL,input[100], *parsed,Test;
    //allow variable number of inputs

    if((variables=calloc(1,sizeof(double)))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed - Variables");
        return(1);
    }
    if((function=calloc(1,sizeof(char)))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed - Functions");
        return(1);
    }


    //get user input
    printf("Calculator. Please enter the equation.\n");
    fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);

    //determine first number, determine function, determine second number
    parsed=input;
    while((Test=*parsed)!='\n' && Test!=EOF && (vCounter<100))
    {
        vCounter++;
        // Determines if character is a digit, if yes it converts the digits into a number.
        // If no it stores the character in a separate array.
        if(isdigit(*parsed))
        {
            variables[Counter]=strtod(parsed,&parsed);
            Counter++;
            if((variables=realloc(variables,sizeof(variables)+sizeof(double)))==NULL)
               {
                   printf("Memory reallocation failed - Variables");
                   free(variables);
                   free(function);
                   return(1);
               }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d\n",fCounter);
            if((function=realloc(function,sizeof(function)+sizeof(char)))==NULL)
               {
                   printf("Memory reallocation failed - Functions");
                   free(function);
                   free(variables);
                   return(1);
               }

            function[fCounter]=*parsed;
            fCounter++;
            parsed++;
        }
    }


free(variables);
free(function);

return(0);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `sizeof(variables)` returns the size of the pointer, not what it points to.

Comment: Of course it does!! Thank you. If you can suggest a method of getting the full length of the memory block and put as an answer that would be great.

Comment: look at this url to see "How to get the size of memory pointed by a pointer?" 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509509/how-to-get-the-size-of-memory-pointed-by-a-pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `realloc` is allocating the wrong size:

```
if((variables=realloc(variables,sizeof(variables)+sizeof(double)))==NULL)
```

should take the actual `Counter` into account

```
if((variables=realloc(variables,Counter*sizeof(double)))==NULL)
```

Additionally you should change the other `realloc` and use

```
if((function=realloc(function,fCounter*sizeof(char)))==NULL)
```

Comment: `realloc(variables,sizeof *variables * Counter)` is less error prone than `realloc(variables,Counter*sizeof(double))`

Comment: @chux I see, with your solution it is not necessary to repeat the type of the stored pointer if it might be changed later. Nice!

Comment: Also consider code review: I see `realloc(variables,sizeof *variables * Counter)` and say "OK" and move on.  I see `realloc(variables,Counter*sizeof(double))` and then need to search about 30 lines up for `double *variables=NULL;` to know its "OK".

Comment: When you use `realloc(variables,sizeof *variables * Counter)` i take it this is asking for the size of the dereferenced pointer, which is (in this case) a double anyway? If this is the case, for clarity this should be the equivalent `realloc(variables,sizeof (*variables) * Counter)` ?

Comment: @Hobojoe It is equivalent, the only difference is that you added parenthesis to the expression. The difference between my suggestion and @chux approach is, that his solution does avoid to repeat the type (in this case `double`). Therefore his suggestion seems to be better.